# How to split string data and push to data table with specific format using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Maybe it's a bad day or I am a stupid. I was trying to create a data table from a file upload (.txt).

> 10|00309|IN3136|EKM|110|13-12-2019|V1.1|||||
>   20|1|01|02|13122019120157_1||Please Enter Mother's First Name|
>   20|2|01|02|13122019120157_2||Please Enter Mother's First Name|
>   20|3|01|02|13122019120157_3||Please Enter Mother's First Name|

is the data inside the text file.

```
var data = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
string[] strArr = null;
int count = 0;
char[] splitchar = { '|' };
strArr = data.Split(splitchar);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Clear();
dt2.Columns.Add("Col0");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col1");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col2");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col3");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col4");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col5");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col6");

for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
 {
   if (count >= 11)
   {
    DataRow _dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
         if (i == 0)
              _dr2["Col0"] = strArr[count+i];
         else if (i == 1)
              _dr2["Col1"] = strArr[count+i];
         else if (i == 2)
              _dr2["Col2"] = strArr[count+i];
         else if (i == 3)
               _dr2["Col3"] = strArr[count+i];
         else if (i == 4)
               _dr2["Col4"] = strArr[count+i];
         else if (i == 5)
                _dr2["Col5"] = strArr[count+i];
          else if (i == 6)
                _dr2["Col6"] = strArr[count+i];

     }
   dt2.Rows.Add(_dr2);
  }
}
```

I am trying to make it like this

[image]

my loops are completely stupid, I know, please point me in the right direction..

Comment: Hi there!  One easy thing you can do is remove all those `if` statements and just have `_dr2[$"Col{i}"] = strArr[count+i];`, this uses string interpolation and gets rid of the bug you've introduced on the last one :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice i tried and it's throwing a 'Message = "Index was outside the bounds of the array."' ..!! concept of 2nd loop itself was a bad idea I think.. don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In production I would use CsvReader as @panagiotiskanavos said. For education you can read all file lines like [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) that will give you `string[]` for each line in file. However reading all file in memory can take all memory for large files so you can check the [StreamReader.ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8) to process file line by line. Then you can split each line by `|` and create table row

Answer (score 3):

That's essentially a CSV file using `|` as the field separator. Instead of writing your own code, you could use a library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) with a custom field separator. You can even parse string values directly into numbers or dates.

CsvHelper offers the [CsvReader](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/) for reading individual fields or full records and [CsvDataReader](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/data-table) to load the CSV file as an `IDataReader` that can be used to load a DataTable or import the data into the database using eg [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_WriteToServer_System_Data_IDataReader_)

Borrowing from the documentation example :

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    // Do any configuration to `CsvReader` before creating CsvDataReader.
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter="|";
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {        
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: The file I am dealing with is in .txt format is that gonna be an issue for reading?

Comment: @FINWIN there's no `txt` format. It's just a text file. CSV files are also text files where the Values are Separated by Commas. That's where the letters CSV come from. It's a loose definition and people often use different separators

Comment: Thanks, It's new information to work with. I will try it for sure. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `File.ReadAllText` ,use `File.ReadAllLines` which is easy to traverse between all the lines as each line is one record .

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines(**@Path to the File**);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var str = lines[i];
                var strarray = str.Split('|');
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will give you the expected result:
Data table filled with the lines from CSV file.

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Col0");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col1");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col2");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col3");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col4");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col5");
dt2.Columns.Add("Col6");

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file path"); //C:\ToBeDeleted\test.txt
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var str = lines[i];
    var strarray = str.Split('|');

    DataRow drow = dt2.NewRow();
    drow["Col0"] = strarray[0];
    drow["Col1"] = strarray[1];
    drow["Col2"] = strarray[2];
    drow["Col3"] = strarray[3];
    drow["Col4"] = strarray[4];
    drow["Col5"] = strarray[5];
    drow["Col6"] = strarray[6];
    dt2.Rows.Add(drow);
}
```

To display your expected result use the below console code:

```
//Displaying as a table.
for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write(dt2.Columns[i].ColumnName + " \t |");
}
Console.WriteLine();
for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(dt2.Rows[j].ItemArray[i] + " \t | ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Below is the output of the above code.

[image: Output from the above program]

Comment: I think I cant use 'strarray[6]' because there will be more values in the file so I won't be able to use the position number directly. Thanks anyway I got the idea. :)

Comment: This is just an example. please mark as answer if you it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I end up doing this. It's working for me (at least for now :D)

```
   private DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string FilePath)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Clear();
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col0");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col1");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col2");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col3");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col4");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col5");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col6");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var str = lines[i];
            if (i > 0)
            {
                var strarray = str.Split('|');
                DataRow _dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
                for (int count = 0; count <= strarray.Length - 1; count++)
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                        _dr2["Col0"] = strarray[count];
                    else if (count == 1)
                        _dr2["Col1"] = strarray[count];
                    else if (count == 2)
                        _dr2["Col2"] = strarray[count];
                    else if (count == 3)
                        _dr2["Col3"] = strarray[count];
                    else if (count == 4)
                        _dr2["Col4"] = strarray[count];
                    else if (count == 5)
                        _dr2["Col5"] = strarray[count];
                    else if (count == 6)
                        _dr2["Col6"] = strarray[count];

                }
                dt2.Rows.Add(_dr2);
            }
        }
        return dt2;
    }
```